# Why do I have to cherry-pick when performing reviews in iOS?

Tags: support, review, design, ios

Starting about 2 days ago, something seems terribly wrong with the various review screens. And this for any SE site, using an iOS device (running 9.3.5), and browser either Safari or Dolphin. No idea so far how it looks like in the most recent iOS version. Looking at similar review pages on a Win PC seems to work fine.

Here is a screenprint of a sample of such review screen:

[image]

Long story short:

- Any of the typical review actions (like flag, upvote, downvote, edit) are all disabled, so that the <kbd>I'm done</kbd> button always remains disabled, so either you use <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd>, or <kbd>Skip</kbd> to move on to the next review (if any).
- Surprisingly, for sites that have audit reviews enabled, this issue does not occur for such audit reviews. I.e. those special reviews can be processed as normal (though you recognize those types of reviews right away of course, great ...).

**Is this intended to be like this, or is it rather some issue that needs to be fixed?**

Notes:

- Not sure if it is related, but the *All time* review counter (the 3,453 in the screenprint above) doesn't get updated either in between 2 reviews, so if you'd click <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> and the next review is shown, that counter didn't get updated either. If however you'd use the <kbd>Review</kbd> button (upper right in the screenprint), to just move on to the next review without any review action for the current review, then that counter does get refreshed to the then current value of it.
- While waiting for those disabled options to become enabled again, the only serious review actions appear to be to [cherry-pick](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/70550) (*****) the 'No Action Needed' reviews, and 'Skip' the reviews of posts that otherwise I'd want to flag, edit, vote, etc.

(*****) It's the time of the year around here:

[image: Cherries]
[image: More Cherries]
[image: Even more Cherries]

Comment: Works fine on my iPad Pro, iOS 13.5.

Comment: *I'm closing this question as off-topic because it belongs on Seasoned Advice, Biology or Gardening & Landscaping* .. ;)

Comment: What browser are you using? Is your version on the list of supported browsers?

Comment: @Luuklag : browser is either Safari or Dolphin (as I recently added in the question). One would assume that at least Safari is in the list of supported browsers, no?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need